# Edit with Full HTML on block changes closing div bracket to its character entity references

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I'm facing issues in writing full html codes in custom block using CKEditor. Even though I select Full HTML mode and toggle to 'source' while writing html content to block, some characters like angular bracket of div tags are automatically changes to its character entity references (&lt or &gt).

Additionally some unwanted characters are inserted to the html content (characters like = or ").

So how can I write chunks of pure html codes to blocks hassle free

PS: I'm using Drupal 8 with core CKEditor

Comment: What are the allowed HTML tags set at for the full_html format?

Comment: @clive Full html for administrator allows all tags i believe. Option for assigning tags are active for restricted html only